# I am going to have a talk with you on may 7 or on 7, may?

Tags: prepositions, dates

I am confused with the order of data, which one I should use?

Comment: Do you tend to use more British English or American English? Also, what are you writing -- is it business or personal correspondence?

Comment: @miltonaut I think tend to use more American English, and it is used in emails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of local, organizational, and often of personal preference. In the US, the form "May 7", or "May 7th", or "May 7, 2019" is very common, as is "05/07/2019". In much of Europe the form "7 May 2019" is common (note no commas) or "2019-05-07" (the ISO date format). Particular organization may have their own perfected style. I don't recall any common style that use4s "7, may". Names of months are usually capitalized in dates.